# add a onclick event to audio timeline with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio

How would you add an onclick event to this audio timeline that goes to the position of audio relative to where you click.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/6bm3jcfm/1/

HTML:

```
<audio src="https://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/44ec3770dad9ca5669c4e32439c4c9a1/sick-n-tired-w-vocals-f0fb72ae83.mp3" id="player"></audio>  
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>

<div class="hp_slide">
     <div class="hp_range"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#play').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('player').play();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('player').pause();
});

var player = document.getElementById('player');    
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    var currentTime = player.currentTime;
    var duration = player.duration;
    $('.hp_range').stop(true,true).animate({'width':(currentTime +.25)/duration*100+'%'},250,'linear');
});
```

CSS

```
 .hp_slide{
        width:100%;
         height:5px;
          background:red;

    }
    .hp_range{
        width:0;
        background:black;
        height:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method would be to get the `offsetX` of the click within the tracking bar and work that out as a percentage of the total width.

Then you can take that percentage and multiply the duration of the audio by it to set the `currentTime` property of the audio element. Something like this:

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var duration = 0;
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    var currentTime = player.currentTime;
    duration = player.duration;
    $('.hp_range').stop(true, true).animate({
        'width': (currentTime + .25) / duration * 100 + '%'
    }, 250, 'linear');
});

$('.hp_slide').click(function(e) {
    var pc = e.offsetX / $(this).width();
    player.currentTime = duration * pc;
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6bm3jcfm/2/)

Comment: Thanks Rory! This is a super simple and efficient example!